# How to refactor checkout process into service

Tags: api, architecture, e-commerce, graphql

I have e-commerce site that I am currently decoupling so it serves as pure backend.

For shopping cart to become an order there is a workflow(checkout) in place that the customer has to go through to place an order. With the checkout now being a backend service I wonder how should I approach it.

Specifically, each new order has to have: items, billing address, delivery address, payment method and shipping method. Admin can create additional fields, alter the flow(order of steps) and so on. With API-centric architecture, I am not sure how to communicate the flow with frontend.

Sure, the frontend will handle the flow, basically, on its own. But for example in the backend logic, the shipping method depends on the provided delivery address and payment method depends on the billing address - to prevent use of cash payment method for customer form different country or to use local bicycle carrier for international destination... for example.

How should I communicate to the client what data are needed, in which order(dependencies), what data I already have and what additional data has to be provided?

Answer (score 1):

You basically handle this with exceptions if the front-end does something out-of-order.  The statefulness of it means that you need to create something, then modify it multiple times.  If you want to enforce this, you would basically create an order (with items),

```
POST /orders <new order>
POST /orders/<ordernum>/items
POST /orders/<ordernum>/billingaddress
POST /orders/<ordernum>/shippingaddress
GET /orders/<ordernum>/availableshippingmethods (throws an error code if billing address not set)
GET /orders/<ordernum>/availablepaymentmethods (throws an error if shipping address not set)
POST /orders/<ordernum>/shippingmethod (throws an error if billing address not set)
```

etc...  Just set up your step dependencies, and throw errors if they do it wrong.

This way the business logic stays on the front-end, and the API requirements for the flow are fairly self-describing (trying to get the shipping method tells you what you forgot to do).

Comment: I will be using graphql so I am unsure about the mutations(rest has one request whereas graphql can post multiple mutations) + I need a way to communicate what information is needed, in what order and what information I already have and what information remains to be provided.